# Piping Javascript output to a custom MySQL table

Tags: javascript, mysql, linux, mongodb, command-line

My setup is as follows:

a) I am running Javascript on a set of figures (sourced from MongoDB) in a Linux command line and getting a set of values.
b) I have a table setup on the same Linux machine in MySQL to hold these values obtained from Javascript.

How do I route the outputs from the Javascript to the MySQL table. I have read the post on connecting to a MySQL database on these forums. But is it also possible to include INSERT statements in that example?

It is a table for internal reporting purposes and the Linux machine is well protected so previous issues that were pointed out regarding security do not apply in my case I guess. But I could be wrong.

Kindly provide your inputs. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: What did you read? Also where is the javascript? Is it node.js or is it some javascript run in bash or something?

Comment: I am running MongoDB queries and storing the final results (which are numbers) into Javascript variables. It is Javascript in bash.

Comment: I don't understand your setup and what exactly you mean. Can you show some code and give examples for your data?

Comment: Hello hgoebl, Sorry for the late reply. Here is the layout of my setup:

Comment: var query = db.sample.count(). After that I have to move the var 'query' directly to a field QUERY in a MySQL table SAMPLE. I am running the above script using the following command in command line: mongo sample query.js where query.js has all the script code.